# How to save values in row after one loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, file

How to save values to row in one cycle, please?

```
import numpy as np

A = 5.4654
B = [4.78465, 6.46545, 5.798]

for i in range(2):
    f = open(f'file.txt', 'a')               
    np.savetxt(f, np.r_[A, B], fmt='%22.16f') 
    f.close()
```

The output is:

```
5.4653999999999998
4.7846500000000001
6.4654499999999997
5.7980000000000000
5.4653999999999998
4.7846500000000001
6.4654499999999997
5.7980000000000000
```

The desired output is:

```
5.4653999999999998     4.7846500000000001     6.4654499999999997    5.7980000000000000
5.4653999999999998     4.7846500000000001     6.4654499999999997    5.7980000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

> newlinestr, optional
> String or character separating lines.

So, perhaps:

```
np.savetxt(f, np.r_[A, B], fmt='%22.16f', newlinestr=' ')
print('\n', file=f)
```

An alternative might be to `np.transpose(np.r_[A, B])` perhaps?